# Feedback analysis question

Tags: feedback

I am having difficulties understanding sections \$j-m\$ in the following question. What's meant by \$R_o,R_i\$? Input and output resistances or rather input/output resistances of feedback unit? If standard input/output resistances, then what's \$R_{in}\$, in section \$k\$?
[image]
First, assuming that \$V_A=50V\$ (despite that all other parameters have changed), in section \$e\$ I found that:

\$A=i_o/i_{sig}=-g_{m1} \cdot \frac{R_{sig}||R_{11}}{R_{sig}||R_{11}+r_{\pi 1}} \cdot r_{\pi 1} \cdot \frac{r_{o1}(\beta+1)}{r_{\pi 2}+r_{o1}+R_E(\beta+1)}=-396.08A/A\$, where \$R_E=2K+R_{22}=3K\Omega,r_{o1}=r_{o2}=V_A/(g_m V_T)=100K\Omega\$

Is that correct?

Next, I'd truly appreciate some help with sections \$j-m\$, at least fully understanding what's asked of me.

Comment: I can't see Vo.

Comment: @Andyaka Truly sorry about that; it's at the collector of Q2.